# xpath optional attribute with inner attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have this xml with a nested element which is optional and I have to make a csv file with attributes from the hierarchy even when the optional attribute is not present.

here is the xml data file:

```
    <dataroot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://mycomp.com/test/xml/model">
    <ELEMENTS>
        <COUNTRY cod_cnt="030">
            <AS cod_as="030308">
             <CONTRACT num_CONTRACT="8715167"/>
             <CONTRACT num_CONTRACT="8715224"/>
            </AS>
         <AS cod_as="030309"/>
    </COUNTRY>
    </ELEMENTS>
</dataroot>
```

I need the elements that have an AS tag even if it has a  CONTRACT or not.
I've wrote something like that but I'm stuck:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/doc:dataroot/doc:ELEMENTS/doc:COUNTRY/doc:AS/doc:CONTRACT">
    <xsl:value-of select="../../@cod_cnt"/>@<xsl:value-of select="../@cod_as"/>
    @<xsl:value-of select="@num_CONTRACT"/>@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@D<xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I know I miss a sort of union but can't go further.

I'm expecting this output:

```
030@030308@8715167@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@D
030@030308@8715224@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@D
030@030309@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@D
```

notice that the first two line are the output I've obtained with attached xls and the third row is handwritten to show you the output I'm expecting.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Can you post your expected output and give more explanation?

Comment: I'v edited a bit the text and added an expected output

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep you `for-each` structure, the statements below should work for you. You need to iterate first on `doc:AS` then on `doc:CONTRACT` if any.

```
 <xsl:for-each select="/doc:dataroot/doc:ELEMENTS/doc:COUNTRY/doc:AS">
        <xsl:value-of select="../@cod_cnt"/><xsl:text>@</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@cod_as"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="doc:CONTRACT>
             <xsl:text>@</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@num_CONTRACT"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@D</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

But personaly, I prefer using template matching and this will give something like this in your case (not tested) :

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Select the <doc:AS> if they are your 'rows' in the csv output -->
    <xsl:apply-template match="/doc:dataroot/doc:ELEMENTS/doc:COUNTRY/doc:AS"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="doc:AS">
    <!-- Do the job for the doc:AS -->
    <xsl:value-of select="../@cod_cnt"/><xsl:text>@</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@cod_as"/>
    <!-- Call template for doc:Contract if any -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="doc:Contract"/>
    <!-- Then add the end of your row -->
    <xsl:text>@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@0@D</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="doc:CONTRACT">
    <!-- Do the job for doc:CONTRACT-->
    <xsl:text>@</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@num_CONTRACT"/>
</xsl:template>
```